# When I use "def" function in my vscode(python) It's returning "syntax error"

Tags: python, vscode-python

I was trying to run the `def` command in my "vscode" but it keeps reporting a strange error that I don't understand and needs some help with. I am showing here a simple example of what is happening.

```py
def hello_function():
    print("yeet")

hello_function()
```

After running the def command I am always greeted with this ERROR:

[image]

Here's the full screenshot:

[image]

**here's the python.python.path**

[image]

Comment: Looks like the error is within VSCode's code that launches your script. It's trying to execute a shell command in the Python interpreter

Comment: what should i do then

Comment: What do you see when you press `Ctrl+Shift+P` and enter Preferences: `Open User Settings`  as the value of `python.pythonPath`?

Comment: it shows "python" ( I don't know to add an image.) . @PraysonW.Daniel

Comment: It does not show the full path to your python?

Comment: no it just states "python" without the inverted commas. @PraysonW.Daniel

Comment: Oh from the picture, press Python to see the value

Comment: tried but nothing's popping up @PraysonW.Daniel

Comment: is there any other thing that i could try @PraysonW.Daniel

Comment: It is something I cannot figure out without seeing your settings. Do you have zoom or google hangout? We can have a session together and you could share your VSCode setting

Comment: i've got zoom , (thanks for the offer i really appreciate it) , when are you free. (it's currently 1:11am in my timezone so i can only be active today for another 49mins)  @PraysonW.Daniel

Comment: however i can also be availble on any other day of your choice @PraysonW.Daniel

Comment: thank you for your support and patience, but another user in this thread helped me solve my problem and I'm also really sorry for bothering you so many times. @PraysonW.Daniel

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should be careful with spaces, Python is a case sensitive programming language.

**UPDATE**

---

- As, I saw the image I understood that the issue was not with spaces, but with the file itself. So, before running the code, **SAVE** the file and then run it.
- You should add Python to the Path environment variable. Hope [this guide](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) helps. Then copy the PATH to VS Code

Comment: I mistakingly answered my own question instead of commenting on your's, please come back.

Comment: You should add Python to the Path environment variable. Hope [this](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) guide helps. Then copy the PATH to VS Code

Comment: thank you for sharing the link and the suggestion it really helped me fixed my problem, though I'm still confused as to how and why did it stopped working before. @georgekrax